# How do I create a PHP loop which automatically posts into a Bootstrap grid?

Tags: php, mysql, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

I'm working on a website right now which is part of a school project.

The following PHP code needs to automatically loop and be posted into a Bootstrap col-md-4 grid until there is no more content. How do I do that? I don't know where to begin.

```
<?php
while ($record = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
  echo '<hr>';
  echo '<h2>' . $record['navn'] . '</h2>';
  echo '<img class="w-100" src="' . $record['url'] . '"/>';
  echo '<pre>';
  echo '<p>' . $record['ingrediens'] . '</p>';
  echo '</pre>';
  echo '<p>' . $record['fremgang'] . '</p>';
}
?>
```

Comment: just replicate what you just did above, squeeze in some div tag with column classes from bootstrap, the flow of the columns will take care of itself

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but i need the grid to be dynamic - i would like to only write code for 1 row, while it has to replicate itself with new content from the database, a loop

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap your loop in the grid

```php
<?php
echo '<div class="col-md-4">';
while ($record = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
  echo '<hr>';
  echo '<h2>' . $record['navn'] . '</h2>';
  echo '<img class="w-100" src="' . $record['url'] . '"/>';
  echo '<pre>';
  echo '<p>' . $record['ingrediens'] . '</p>';
  echo '</pre>';
  echo '<p>' . $record['fremgang'] . '</p>';
}
echo '</div>'
?>
```

You're also able to only show it if there are records by wrapping *that* in an `if (rowcount)` sort of check.

Comment: Thank you for your answer - however, i doesn't seem to work. Its printing the content vertically below the first "box of content", while it should be posting it horizontally to the boostrap grid. Any solution for this?

Comment: That just sounds like a placement issue or further formatting issue. Try moving the block of code to be where it "should" be in the code. I'm unable to "guess" your code and give an accurate placement based on the information provided.

Answer (score 0):

Update:

I created this loop, however only the first item in the grid is showing properly, the rest (the images) are expanding through the grid. Any ideas what this might be?

```
    <?php

echo '<div class="row">';
$counter=0;
while ($record = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    echo '<div class="col-sm">';

    echo '<hr>';
    echo '<h2>' . $record['navn'] . '</h2>';
    echo '<img class="w-100" src="' . $record['url'] . '"/>';
    echo '<pre>';
    echo '<p>' . $record['ingrediens'] . '</p>';
    echo '</pre>';
    echo '<p>' . $record['fremgang'] . '</p>';

    echo "</div>";


    $counter++;
    //Antal kolonner
    if($counter=="3"){
        $counter=0;
        echo '<div class="w-100"></div>';
    }
}
echo"</div>";

?>
```